# modprobe nouveau fails, as it tries to load 'off.'

Tags: nouveau, modprobe

When I try `modprobe nouveau` I am greeted with:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

There is no blacklist for nouveau in `/etc/modprobe.d/` so I am not sure why this fails?

```
bram@Workstation:/etc/modprobe.d$ grep off *
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-3 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-6 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-9 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-11 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-12 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-19 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-21 off
blacklist-rare-network.conf:alias net-pf-36 off
```

The reason I want nouveau is that I would like to use it to switch video modes for me, for the linux framebuffer.

I am not trying to run X on it.

Currently, EFI VGA framebuffer does not let me switch modes.

**kernel:** 5.13.0-28-generic

**OS:** Ubuntu: 21.10

**GPU:** RTX 3070

Comment: Trying to make a RTX3070 work with `nouveau` is probably a waste of time. Install the Nvidia drivers and be done with it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I just want the nouveau framebuffer, not X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blacklisting in Ubuntu is done at multiple file locations, so checking `/etc/modprobe.d` is not enough:

There is also `/lib/modprobe.d/` which has a `nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` in  it.

This file specifies:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```